# empty file after recording and turning off the mobile device after 1-2 seconds

Tags: java, android, io

I write the file to the directory and after 1-2 seconds I remove the battery from the device. After writing, I open the file and output it to the log in order to make sure that it is recorded. So it is recorded successfully. But after turning on the device I open the file and it is empty.

What could be the reason?

Used to read and write FileOutputStream/FileInputStream, FileWriter/FileReader, FileUtils from Apache Commons IO.

```
public static void storeForReversal(XmlTag sourceTag_TrnAddRq) {
    String toStore = sourceTag_TrnAddRq.buildXmlString();
    File sdFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "reversal");
    try {
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(sdFile, toStore, "US-ASCII");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ZLog.add(MyApplication.TAG, "ERROR store file Reversal: ", e);
    }
}

public static String restoreForReversal() {
    String result = "";
    File sdFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "reversal");
    try {
        result = FileUtils.readFileToString(sdFile, "US-ASCII");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ZLog.add(MyApplication.TAG, "ERROR restore file Reversal: ", e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Device File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHwiH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that information is saved in a file during an emergency power off, you need to use `fo.getFD().sync()`:

```
try (FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(sdFile)) {
    fo.write(text.getBytes());
    fo.flush();
    fo.getFD().sync();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "");
}
```